# How to use sequence when testing async methods?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, async-await, moq

I am using [Moq.Sequences](https://github.com/dwhelan/Moq-Sequences) and I am having trouble with testing async methods. 
When I do this:

```
[Test]
public async Task Demo()
{
    using (Sequence.Create())
    {        
        _fooMock.Setup(f => f.Fooxiate()).InSequence();

        _barMock.Setup(b => b.Baronize()).InSequence();

        var result = await _cut.DoMyStuffAsync();

        Assert.AreEqual("someString", result);
    }
}
```

The I get an exception in the production code when `calling _foo.Fooxiate()` saying:

> Moq.Sequences.SequenceUsageException: 'Mock invocation can only be called with an active MockSequence created with MockSequence.Create()

#### **Am I doing something wrong or is testing of call sequence in async methods not supported?**

Here is the full demo code including the above mentioned production code:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Moq;
using Moq.Sequences;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace TestingAsync.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class SomeClassTests
    {
        private SomeClass _cut;

        private Mock<IFoo> _fooMock;
        private Mock<IBar> _barMock;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            _fooMock = new Mock<IFoo>();
            _barMock = new Mock<IBar>();

            _cut = new SomeClass(_fooMock.Object, _barMock.Object);
        }

        [Test]
        public async Task Demo()
        {
            using (Sequence.Create())
            {
                _fooMock.Setup(f => f.Fooxiate()).InSequence();

                _barMock.Setup(b => b.Baronize()).InSequence();

                var result = await _cut.DoMyStuffAsync();

                Assert.AreEqual("someString", result);
            }
        }
    }

    public class SomeClass
    {
        private readonly IFoo _foo;
        private readonly IBar _bar;

        public SomeClass(IFoo foo, IBar bar)
        {
            _bar = bar;
            _foo = foo;
        }

        public async Task<string> DoMyStuffAsync()
        {
            return await Task.Run(() => DoMyStuff());
        }

        private string DoMyStuff()
        {
            _foo.Fooxiate();

            _bar.Baronize();

            return "someString";
        }
    }

    public interface IBar
    {
        void Baronize();
    }

    public interface IFoo
    {
        void Fooxiate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44982738/240733) explains correctly how Moq.Sequences <strike>doesn't</strike> didn't properly support `async` / `await` due to its use of `[ThreadStatic]`.

Based on the OP's request, I've updated that library to provide better support for modern concurrent programming patterns. (Hopefully, people are programming with `Task`s these days, not `Thread`s.)

Starting with version 2.1.0, you can make Moq.Sequences track the ambient sequence using a `AsyncLocal<Sequence>` instead of a `[ThreadStatic]` variable. This means that the ambient sequence can "flow" across async boundaries such as an `await` and still be visible in the continuation (which might run on a different thread).

For reasons of backwards compatibility, you currently need to opt in to the new behavior by doing the following before any of your tests run:

```
Sequence.ContextMode = SequenceContextMode.Async;
```

At this time of writing, the new behavior hasn't been extensively tested [so issue and bug reports are welcome](https://github.com/dwhelan/Moq-Sequences/issues).

Comment: Thanks for adding this stakx! Impressive :)

Comment: I was not previously aware of AsyncLocal<T>, thanks for teaching me!

Comment: @JohnBindel: It's a fairly recent addition to .NET (4.6) which I only learnt about a short while ago from the awesome Castle DynamicProxy folks. Before .NET 4.6 there was something even more arcane: `CallContext`. Have fun with it. :)

Comment: Thanks again stakx. @JohnBindel I marked this answer as the (now) correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Moq.Sequences is not written to be multi-threaded as it uses the `[ThreadStatic]` attribute to keep track of the ambient Sequence.

```
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static Sequence instance;
```

The result is that the ambient Sequence is only stored for the current thread. Then you call `Task.Run` which spawns a background thread to do work. This results in the exception being thrown because instance is null for that thread.

```
if (Instance == null)
    throw new SequenceUsageException(context + " can only be called with an active MockSequence created with MockSequence.Create()");
```

[https://github.com/dwhelan/Moq-Sequences → `src/Moq.Sequences/Sequence.cs`](https://github.com/dwhelan/Moq-Sequences/blob/e38196d06350f35157e2b6c19377ccb14981a9a8/src/Moq.Sequences/Sequence.cs)

There is not a good way for Moq.Sequences to be able to guarantee order of calls in async code because:

1. Concurrent code does not typically have deterministic order of execution.
2. Async is an abstraction over threads and because of that is even less predictable than threads. There are many techniques that result in non-deterministic sequence of calls, such as doing work in background threads with Task.Run, using Parallel.For/ForEach, using TPL dataflow, using Task.WhenAll, etc.